# Android : Sqlite DB insertion

Tags: android, mobile, android-sqlite, sql-insert

Can we insert 1000 records in one go in Sqlite db in android. I know there is an approach of putting the loop and then calling the insert for 1000 times ?? Is there any other approach for this which is good in performance. And if this is the only approach, how much my performance would be impacted by this??

Answer (score 0):

```
database.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF");
```

Will enhance the speed database operations.

But it is risky in some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use transactions for such scenarios.

Pseudocode:

```
db.beginTransaction();
for (entry : listOfEntries) {
    db.insert(entry);
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Check [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-sqlite-transaction-tutorial.html) post.
It has example of inserting values to database with and without transaction.
Also it has time measurment for this approaches(In this post difference is more than 100 times while inserting 100 records).